# Using icefaces with primefaces?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, icefaces

i was wondering if it's possible to use in one application two different JSF components like icefaces and primefaces ?
if that's possible what are the limitations/problems of such approach ?
and how can i configure that in my web.xml ?

Comment: Why would you like to do such a thing? And what kind of limitations/problems did you expect? AFAIK the best recommendation i can give is to use primefaces without icefaces!

Answer (score 2):

it is possible... but be aware that the latest Icefaces is actually a 100% wrapped Primefaces... (they took the entire primefaces source code....)

INMO, you better stick to one of them only... And since Primefaces is the **original** one and is **super active project** I'd say without a doubt is the right choice...

read this

[IceFaces Copies PrimeFaces Line by Line](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1692)

Comment: I would prefer the original (and not support the copy kings from Icefaces).